# use javascript (or JQuery) in a standalone HTML file to select an XML and transform

Tags: xslt

I need a way to transform XML to HTML (using XSL) but without a server. So, I want to create a standalone HTML file (with hardcodes XSL path and name). 
Allow the user to select an XML 
Transform it with the XSL and display results in browser

Original XML cannot be changed (so cannot just embed XSL in XML)

Is this possible? Everything I found requires post, but I'm not using a server

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. And you don't need javascript to do it, but you can use javascript if you want.

Just look at the previous (XSLT question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964917]

Use a processing-instruction like...

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="soccer.xslt"?>
```

Refer:

- Direct linkage through pi: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/
- Transform through javascript:

  - http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=482
  - [Calling XSLT from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677145/calling-xslt-from-javascript)